# Help with more neo-Latin: making sense of a Hebrew calque

Tags: new-latin

Hello: I am back again with more neo-Latin from Lawrence of Brindisi. This time, it's his Latin rendering of Psalm 45:13-14

"tota gloriosa filia regis intrinsecus propter intertexturas, induta auro in recamatis"

I am stumbling in particular on *intertexturas* and *in recamatis*. *Intertexturas* I take to mean "interweavings"-->"interwoven clothes". "*ricamatus* seems to me to mean the same thing as *ricamus*/*ricamum* (https://logeion.uchicago.edu/ricamum): Opus acu pictum. In Italian, *ricamare* means embroider; it's possible that Lawrence came up with the form *ricamatus* on analogy with his native language.

So: all glorious [is the] daughter of the king inside [the palace?] on account of [lit.] weavings/woven clothes, dressed/having dressed herself in garments embroidered with gold."

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Your interpretation of *recamatis* as a variant of *ricamatis* and *ricamatis* as an Italianism is probably right, but also be aware the Latin mashes together two separate Hebrew sentences. *Tota gloriosa filia regis intrinsecus propter intertexturas auro* renders כָּל־כְּבוּדָּה בַת־מֶלֶךְ פְּנִימָה מִמִּשְׁבְּצוֹת זָהָב לְבוּשָׁהּ׃ ([Psalms 45:14](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2645.htm) in the MT, 45:13 in most Christian Bibles for some reason),  *Induta in recamatis* is the start of the next verse.

Comment: @Cairnarvon It looks like *recamatis* renders *riqmot* from the next verse (and is maybe just an attempt to Latinize that Hebrew word?). *Induta auro* renders זָהָב לְבוּשָׁהּ (syntactically inaccurately as that is not a constituent in the Hebrew).

Comment: @TKR Oh, you're right, and that's an interesting point. Apparently רִקמָה and Italian *ricamare* are ~cognate: the Italian is a loan from Arabic رقم *raqm* (I can't read Arabic). Presumably it came through Spanish *recamar*, which could explain the vowel used. To what extent Lawrence of Brindisi will have been aware of that (and whether he even knew Latin never had that word) is another matter.